# "scons qemu" error "sh: 1: qemu: not found"

Tags: operating-system, qemu

I want learn a toy OS FreeNOS, its doc says use "scons qemu" to boot it. But I run this command shows:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for -m32 ... (cached) yes
Checking for -fno-stack-protector ... (cached) yes
Checking for -O0 ... (cached) yes
Checking for -g3 ... (cached) yes
Checking for -Wall ... (cached) yes
Checking for -W ... (cached) yes
Checking for -Wno-unused-parameter ... (cached) yes
Checking for -fno-builtin ... (cached) yes
Checking for -nostdinc ... (cached) yes
Checking for -Wno-write-strings ... (cached) yes
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
qemu -usb -cdrom boot/boot.iso
sh: 1: qemu: not found
scons: *** [qemu] Error 127
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

But I have installed qemu, when I run "ls /usr/bin", It shows :
[image]

here are many items about but no one is named "qemu"

so I want know how could I boot this OS..

Comment: Please check if `scons qemu-launcher` helps; I don't have any experience with it though, just a guess.

Comment: It's doesnt work, but still thank you.@Am_I_Helpful

Answer (score 0):

You've nearly answered your question yourself. qemu is not found because there is no qemu.

Simply create a symlink to your desired target platform. Looking at freenos.org x86, mips and arm are supported, so most likely **ln -s qemu-system-i386 qemu** should work.

For clarification: all qemu binaries are of the form qemu-system-< arch > or qemu-< arch >[-static]. qemu-system-* emulates a hole system (e.g a x86 pc with disk, network and graphics card), whereas with qemu-< arch > you can run a single binary of architecture < arch > on your current host architecture.